# Is Comet easier in ASP.NET with Asynchronous Pages?

Tags: asp.net, asynchronous, jetty, comet

I don't mean to ask, *is Comet easier in ASPNET than in Jetty?*  I mean, *is Comet easier inn either ASPNET or Jetty, as compared to other alternatives?*  I think the asynch capabilities of ASP.NET and Jetty specifically make Comet more scalable when implemented on those platforms and I'd like to confirm that.

ASPNET introduced "Asynchronous pages" back in 2005.   The idea was to [apply the familiar .NET asynch model to ASP.NET page processing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163725.aspx).

```
public partial class AsyncPage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private WebRequest _request;

    void Page_Load (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AddOnPreRenderCompleteAsync (
            new BeginEventHandler(BeginAsyncOperation),
            new EndEventHandler (EndAsyncOperation)
        );
    }

    IAsyncResult BeginAsyncOperation (object sender, EventArgs e, 
        AsyncCallback cb, object state)
    {
        _request = WebRequest.Create("http://msdn.microsoft.com");
        return _request.BeginGetResponse (cb, state);
    }
    void EndAsyncOperation (IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        string text;
        using (WebResponse response = _request.EndGetResponse(ar))
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = 
                new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                text = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }

        Regex regex = new Regex ("href\\s*=\\s*\"([^\"]*)\"", 
            RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(text);

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(1024);
        foreach (Match match in matches)
        {
            builder.Append (match.Groups[1]);
            builder.Append("<br/>");
        }

        Output.Text = builder.ToString ();
    }
}
```

**Q1:** Doesn't this make ASP.NET scale much better for Comet-style applications? 
Has anyone used this and tested it?

I think that other server-side frameworks also have something similar.  If I'm not mistaken Jetty has something like this, to enable better scale in Comet scenarios.

**Q2:** Can anyone shed light on *that*?

Comment: From what I can see, asynchronous in this case appears to be for how threads are handled on the server... As far as I know, the output is still sent in one chunk when the page is finished processing, which completely eliminates the possibility for Comet to work with the ASP.NET model... I would be happy to be proven wrong though.

Comment: Hey Blixt - check out WebSync (http://www.frozenmountain.com/websync). Comet is indeed not only possible, but proven with IIS/.NET.

Comment: jvenema, that wasn't the question. The question was, *is it easier or more scalable using async pages*.

Comment: Sorry Cheeso, I was replying to Blixt. In answer to your question, definitely easier - you don't have to write a full web server to handle it, and from testing WebSync and comparing to Jetty apparently more scalable, although I've not done a true side-by-side comparison (same machine, etc) to really confirm that 100%.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The asynchronous processing in .NET does indeed provide a basis for building comet applications.  Specifically, it's the IHttpAsyncHandler that can be used as a foundation.

That said, without a third-party library, implementing Comet from scratch is... difficult.  There's a .NET implementation of Comet for IIS called [WebSync](http://www.frozenmountain.com/websync) that would compare against Jetty.

Comment: Too bad there is no open source product in the ASP.NET space that I can find. Plenty of choices in the Java space.

Comment: @Kelly: There's an open source implementation at GitHub called aspComet: https://github.com/nmosafi/aspComet